# Magento 1.9 Patch MPERF-10509 - Invalid HTTP response version

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

We're on Magento `1.9.2.4 CE` and applied patch `MPERF-10509-CE`.

In the admin dashboard, the dashboard sales chart is broken and returning a 503 error in console. Magento error report shows:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:32:"Invalid HTTP response version: 2";i:1;s:1412:"#0 /lib/Zend/Http/Response.php(665): Zend_Http_Response->__construct(200, Array, '\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHD...', '2', false)
#1 /lib/Zend/Http/Client.php(1098): Zend_Http_Response::fromString('HTTP/2 200 \r\nda...')
#2 /lib/Varien/Http/Client.php(61): Zend_Http_Client->request('GET')
#3 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(100): Varien_Http_Client->request('GET')
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->tunnelAction()
#5 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('tunnel')
#6 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
```

Any ideas what is going on and how to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Editing file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/graph.phtml` around line 61.

Change:

```
<?php echo $this->getChartUrl(false) ?>
```

To:

```
<?php echo $this->getChartUrl(true) ?>
```

Now the chart loads from `https://www.image-charts.com/chart` api. I'm not entirely sure if this is the proper solution, but it allows the chart to display.